# Как добавить текст в textarea с того div по которому кликнул? Помогите дописать код

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<textarea id="mytextarea" required></textarea>

<div id="bl1">test1</div>
<div id="bl1">test2</div>
<div id="bl1">test3</div>
<div id="bl1">test4</div>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#bl1').click(function() {
            alert("dd");
            document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += $(this).text();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Моя проблема. Когда кликаю на первый div c id="bl1" текст добавляется все ок, но когда кликаю на другие div c id="bl1" текст не добавляется.

Как правильно написать JS чтобы добавлялся в textarea тот текст блока по которому я клинул?

Comment: Вы в курсе что id это уникальный параметр и должен использоваться для каждого элемента свой? Может стоит всем div присвоить класс и повесить событие на него?

Comment: @SkyFox забыл об этом, так и сделал, изменил id на class и все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Новый вопрос задавайте в новом вопросе

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо. Так и сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в коде ошибка - не может быть несколько одинаковых ID в элементах

```
<div class = 'b1' id="bl1">test1</div>
<div class = 'b1' id="bl2">test2</div>
<div class = 'b1' id="bl3">test3</div>
<div class = 'b1' id="bl4">test4</div>
```

поэтому и срабатывает только один (первый)

Решение - создай один класс для всех элементов, на которые ты нажимаешь и отслеживай нажатие на элемент по классу

```
$('.bl').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += $(this).text();
});
```

в this вроде как будет именно тот элемент по которому ты нажал

И еще - чтобы получить дополнительную информацию об элементе - вызывай функцию с параметром (event)

```
$('.bl').click(function(e){
  // в e находится много интересного и полезного
  document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

На странице может быть только УНИКАЛЬНЫЙ id
id1,id2,id3 etc.

Comment: Я в div изменил id на класс и заработало все.

Comment: @Tokwiro, а ты жесток, лучше все таки какой-то более-менее уникальный идентификатор использовать, чем все div на сайте слушать (а их тысячи могут быть). Мне, например, нравится способ когда всем нужным элементам присваивается одинаковый класс и по этому классу уже и вешается обработчик событий.

P.S. ответ был по поводу предложения отслеживать все <div>  - $('div').click...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#uniq_id').click(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    $('#mytextarea').val(div.val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

На случай, если принципиально нужно использовать неуникальные id(мало ли, может исходный DOM от вас не зависит), придётся перебрать все элементы на странице:

```js
[...document.all]
  .filter(el => el.id === 'bl1')
  .forEach(el => 
     el.addEventListener('click', ev => document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += ev.target.innerText))
```

```css
#bl1{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea" required></textarea>

<div id="bl1">test1</div>
<div id="bl1">test2</div>
<div id="bl1">test3</div>
<div id="bl1">test4</div>
```

Либо слушать вообще все клики в документе и фильтровать нужные:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if(ev.target.id==='bl1') {
    document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += ev.target.innerText;
  }
});
```

```css
#bl1{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea" required></textarea>

<div id="bl1">test1</div>
<div id="bl1">test2</div>
<div id="bl1">test3</div>
<div id="bl1">test4</div>
<div id="bl2">Ignore</div>
```

***Внимание:*** Этот ответ не является советом или рекомендацией к действию, просто изыскание на тему.

Answer (score 0):

css селектор `#id` - возвращает только первый элемент с таким `id`, так как значение атрибута `id` должно быть уникально на странице.

Но можно использовать [селектор по атрибуту](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```js
$('[id="bl1"]').click(function() {
  document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += $(this).text();
})
```

```css
#bl1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytextarea" required></textarea>

<div id="bl1">test1</div>
<div id="bl1">test2</div>
<div id="bl1">test3</div>
<div id="bl1">test4</div>
```